# Como pegar valor de um formulário com AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-module

estou começando com AngularJS e surgiu uma dúvida que me parece ser simples.

Estou fazendo um carrinho de compras (só pra aprendizado mesmo) com o pouco que aprendi (ng-controller, ng-repeat, ng-model, etc).

Tenho uma lista que vem do Controller e quero adicionar automaticamente no carinho. Porém, gostaria de saber como pego o valor da quantidade e passo para a função no Controller... utilizei ng-model='quantidade' e tentei recuperar via {{ quantidade }}, o que obviamente não funcionou.

Podem me ajudar?

Meu código: https://jsfiddle.net/r7r99sr9/

Obrigado! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma variavel no controller referente a esse ng-model e pegue o valor do `$scope.quantidade`, depois é só passar a variavel para a função.

```
       //Pega o valor do input
        var quantidade = $scope.quantidade;
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo 100% funcional de como você poderá recuparar os dados informados via javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function ok() {
      var scope = $('#entityScope').scope();
      alert(scope.firstName);
   }
</script>
<body>

<p>Try to change the names.</p>

<div id="entityScope" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
<br>
<input type="button" value="Ok" onclick="ok()">
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName= "John";
    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```